# problem in running flutter in real android device

Tags: android, flutter, debugging

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dT2dg.png)In flutter I have problem in usb debugging in Android device, it shows blank screen after running, in web it's working fine
in console its showing                                                                                                                                                                     Launching lib\main.dart on I2011 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk...
I/flutter ( 3705): The Dart VM service is listening on
Launching lib\main.dart on I2011 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk...
I/flutter ( 3705): The Dart VM service is listening on

i tried changing versions of flutter, android studio

Comment: can u share ur (android/app/build.gradle) screen shot ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @kupendar, Please share code and screen shots(if possible), for easy and fast resolve problem. description is not enough to identify problem which you faced.

Comment: @Pradip Is vivo phone doesn't work for usb debugging

Comment: I am using vivo (iqoo) mobile , I think it doesn't support for flutter for usb debugging

Comment: @JB Jason  I have used my friend's mobile (Realme)  it's working fine, I think there is problem in vivo(iqoo) mobiles